# "Случаи вроде A, B, C..." — запятая

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

У нас возник спор с другим участником Википедии после того, как я убрал запятую в таком выражении в [этой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AA) статье:

> В отличие от нынешней орфографии, разделительный Ъ ставился не только перед буквами йотированных гласных, но и в некоторых других **случаях(,) вроде** съэкономить, разъикаться, двухъаршинный и т. п. (в том числе он позволял различать на письме слова подарочный и подъарочный).

Мне чутьё говорит, что запятая противоречит интонации этой и подобных фраз. *"Вроде"* здесь аналогично *"типа".* Ведь очень странно будет поставить запятую в словосочетании "случаи типа этого". Собеседник возражает, что количество пунктов говорит в пользу запятой, но мне кажется, что если и продолжить список, то всё равно запятая будет странно смотреться.

Comment: Боюсь, что слова про количество пунктов будут поняты неправильно. Я (тот самый собеседник) говорю, что оборот "вроде..." является уточняющим к словам "некоторых других", которые относятся к тому же слову "случаях", что и сам оборот.

Answer (score 3):

Даю другой ответ (после утреннего просветления и общения с духами).

Запятая ставится:

*В отличие от нынешней орфографии, разделительный Ъ ставился не только перед буквами йотированных гласных, но и в некоторых **другИх случаях, вроде** съэкОномить, разъикАться, двухъаршИнный и т. п.*

Это ряд со значением **пояснения**, его надо правильно прочитать. При обособлении ударение падает на слово "других", поэтому делается пауза. В одну фразу (с ударением только на членах ряда) эта конструкция не читается.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

1) И тогда он произнес речь, которой я совершенно не понял, а **знакомые** **слова** вроде **шары, колеса или перо** имели явно не то значение, какое я с ними связывал. [Владимир Войнович.  2001.10.19]

Здесь мы имеем приложение перед рядом: слова (вроде) шары, колеса или перо.

2) Если оборот сложно  встроить в предложение, то можно его обособить со значением пояснения, например: *...он выписывает тем же карандашиком **мудрёные словА, вроде "тавтология", "повтор", "неудачная метафора", "чрезмерная гиперболичность"**, сладко зевает  и косится при этом украдкой на свои ручные часики…* [Аркадий Мильчин. В лаборатории редактора Лидии Чуковской // «Октябрь», 2001]

Здесь ударением выделяется однородный ряд сказуемых, а перечислительный оборот обособляется как попутное пояснение.

3) Кстати, привет толковому словарю с неправильным примером: *Любит употреблять словечки вроде "голубчик", "соколик".*

**Не нужна здесь запятая.**

Comment: По п.3) Грамота с Вами [согласна](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=226633).

Comment: @Sharon Странный пример из Мильчина: похоже, что не хватает запятых — все кавычки слились. P. S. А в толковом словаре еще и **_как-то_** через дефис. https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/100072/%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Римма Михайлова Ладно, запятые можно поставить, а примеры другие найти. Важно то, что в этой теме возможны оба варианта, что определяется по содержанию и интонационной структуре предложения конкретного предложения. Кстати, а  как надо писать "как-то"?

Comment: @grizzly Большое спасибо за информацию.

Comment: Мне несмотря ни на что почему-то по-прежнему не хочется ставить запятую и в нашем случае, и в случае с мудрёными словами. Не чувствую существенной разницы, если честно. ;)

Comment: Артем, хорошо звучит:  "но и в некоторых других случаях вроде съэкОномить, разъикАться, двухъаршИнный"? Ведь вам нужно обозначить перечислительную интонацию, поставить три ударения на однородных членах. И вот не первый однородный член  вы "навешиваете" еще 7 слов. Удобно читается и понимается? Одно или два слова не помешают,  но только не такое количество. Тогда надо писать просто: "но и в случаях вроде", здесь запятая не нужна. А добавили еще пару слов, и уже паузу надо делать.

Comment: Фактически этот оборот по смыслу, структуре и интонации соответствует такой конструкции: но и в некоторых другИх случаях, таких как...

Comment: Ну может быть... Надо привыкнуть к этому и переосмыслить. А каких слов **семь**, так и не понял?

Comment: Чем больше слов стоит перед "вроде" (но и в некоторых других случаях вроде), тем сложнее это прочитать в одну фразу, приходится делать паузу. Да и структура предложения не сразу улавливается, может показаться, что все эти слова относятся к первому члену однородного ряда.

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря:

ВРОДЕ II. частица. Разг. 1. Как будто, кажется, словно. Он в. заболел. В. ничего, неплохой парнишка. В. Володи (разг.; о ком-, чём-л. сомнительном по своим свойствам, качествам и т.п.). 2. (употр. перед перечислением). Как то, а именно. ***Любит употреблять словечки, в.: "голубчик", "соколик".***

Тогда получается:

*В отличие от нынешней орфографии, разделительный Ъ ставился не только перед буквами йотированных гласных, но и в некоторых других случаях, **вроде (как то):** съэкономить, разъикаться...*

Это оформление по образцу обобщающего слова перед однородным рядом.

Сравнить: *В отличие от нынешней орфографии, разделительный Ъ ставился не только перед буквами йотированных гласных, но и **в словах вроде** съэкономить, разъикаться, двухъаршинный..*.

В этом случае нет предупреждения о перечислении (некоторых других, а именно), и тогда "в словах" будет являться приложением, запятая не ставится.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, видел на Грамоте это. То есть вы тоже поставили бы запятую? Кстати, "как то" по нынешним нормам пишется раздельно в значении союза, смотрите [тут](https://aif.ru/society/education/kak-to_ili_kak_to_kak_pravilno). Непонятно, почему Грамота не исправит это. Есть старые нормы, которых хочется придерживаться и сейчас, но не в этом случае, — плохо понимаю, зачем вообще писали через дефис. Кстати, буду благодарен, если скажете, правильно я оставил запятую перед тире или нет, никак не могу разобраться, когда она съедается.

Comment: Точно, Артем, спасибо, я знаю, машинально переписала.

Comment: Думаю, что, запятая не нужна. Запятая закрывает определительные обороты и придаточные, а здесь однородные отношения (есть старые нормы, но не в этом случае...). Это БСП, тире присоединительное. Возможен единый знак (запятая и тире), но здесь он кажется лишним

Comment: Спасибо, что прокомментировали запятую! Я правильно понял, что второй вариант оформления возможен и с оригинальными словами? То есть можно без знаков и с запятой и двоеточием перед и после "вроде". Верно?